# Can I pass a string into fopen()? in c

Tags: c

My goal is to gather input and open files based on that input.

```
FILE* 
open_input_file (char* fileName) //opens source file to be read
{ 
 return fopen(fileName, "r");
}
```

In an earlier function, I collect input from the user and save it to fileName. When I debug the program, it tells me fopen is returning NULL. That's not what I want, and I'm not sure where the problem is.

```
int main(void)
{    FILE* inFile = NULL;
     char infileName[32] = {'\0'};
     gather_input(infileName); // infileName is an output parameter for this
     inFile = open_input_file(infileName);
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`fopen`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) [returns `NULL`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html#tag_03_176_04), the open failed. `errno` will hold the [failure code](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html#tag_03_176_05) and [`strerror(errno)`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html) will return a short description of why the open failed.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

...

int main(void)
{    FILE* inFile = NULL;
     char infileName[32] = {'\0'};
     gather_input(infileName); // infileName is an output parameter for this
     if (!(inFile = open_input_file(infileName))) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error opening '%s': %s\n", 
                 infileName, strerror(errno));
     } else {
         // open successful
         ...
     }
}
```

## Off-topic

`gather_input` better make sure `infileName` is null-terminated to prevent buffer overflows. The simplest way to do this is to define the size of the file name buffer as a macro and set the last character to 0.

```
#define FILENAMELEN 32
void gather_input(char infileName[]) {
    ...
    infileName[FILENAMELEN-1]=0;
}

 int main(void)
{    FILE* inFile = NULL;
     char infileName[FILENAMELEN] = {'\0'};
```

This isn't very flexible. You could instead pass the size of the file name buffer into `gather_input`.

```
#define LENGTH(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
void gather_input(char infileName[], size_t len) {
    ...
    infileName[len-1]=0;
}

 int main(void)
{    FILE* inFile = NULL;
     char infileName[32] = {'\0'};
     gather_input(infileName, LENGTH(infileName)); // infileName is an output parameter for this
```

An alternative to setting the last character, if using standard string manipulation functions, is to use the `strl*` functions ([`strlcpy` and `strlcat`](http://www.gratisoft.us/todd/papers/strlcpy.html)) rather than their unbounded cousins. If you aren't using `strl*`, you should be using [`strncpy`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html) and [`strncat`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncat.html).

Comment: I just added an error check in the gather_input function to ensure infileName is null-terminated. That didn't seem to solve the problem. I also added your code (#included errno.h and added the if statement), but I'm not quite sure what's going on there. Where is the error message supposed to print?

Comment: The null-termination thing has less to do with the problem you're facing and more to do with preventing buffer overflows (see updated answer). RE: where. If you're running this from a command line, in the terminal. If you're running this from a debugger, in the console.

Comment: What does that mean, in the terminal, or in the console? For some reason when I debug, the program skips over the if statement from your code. I posted the code on pastebin (http://pastebin.com/Qbrh1v4A). While I don't think I omitted anything important, there's a chance I did. You can glance at it if you'd like, and I would appreciate it, but I definitely understand if you don't want to.

Comment: The terminal is wherever you type commands. The console is where the debugger displays text output; how you view it depends on what IDE you're using. I'll at least compile the code and see if I can step through it; that shouldn't take long.

Comment: One problem with your null-termination is you use `strlen`, which only works on strings that are properly null-terminated. Also, the `GUARD` macro in your header could theoretically conflict with some other macro. The standard is to use "<header>_H" (`MORSE_H`, in this case). Thirdly, if `open_input_file` fails, you shouldn't proceed with processing. Notice the `else` block in my sample; that's where the input file should be processed.

Comment: In `open_output_file`, you open `*fileName` (which is the first character of `fileName`) rather than `fileName`.

Comment: When I ran it, it didn't enter the block, but that's because `inFile` wasn't null (i.e. the open was successful). I can't say what's going on on your computer.

Comment: Good point with my use of strlen. I don't quite understand what's going on in the last code you posted (I haven't seen #define lines like that, only used as constants. I'll google that. Also, I don't know what size_t is or sizeof() does, but I'll google these things.) Thanks for letting me know about the guard code standard; it's good to know, and I'll implement that from now on.

Comment: My program isn't crashing anymore. Thanks a lot for the help; I appreciate it!

Comment: There's a great Q&A on SO about the `LENGTH` macro (though it might be named `SIZE`), but I can't find it right now. Note that it only works on arrays and not pointers. It wouldn't work within `gather_input`, for example. Out of curiosity, what fixed the crash?

Comment: It ran after I fixed the error in the open_output_file() function. It wasn't even getting past the open_input_file() before though, so there were some other fixes too.

Comment: I still don't fully understand the macro you made [#define LENGTH(a) ((a) / sizeof(a[0])) ]. If I instead do, in my gather_input function, something like...      if (inputFile[sizeof(inputFile) - 1] != '\0')    inputFile[sizeof(inputFile) - 1] = '\0'; /*sorry for format, I don't know how to make it look better in these comments*/                     Will that accomplish the goal of checking for null-termination?

Comment: Ok, I guess that would just ensure the last char in the entire array was a null char, which is what you accomplished with the code you entered right above that. I just don't understand what is happening when you divide the string (a, in your macro) by the size of one of it's components. Is the result just the length the string was initialized to?

Comment: I left a `sizeof` out of `LENGTH`. It should make more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you checked that the file pointed to by inFilename exists on your HDD ?
2. Check the value of infileName in your debugger or put a printf statement to show the value on screen.  printf("'%s'\n", infileName);
3. Did you call fclose() on your file inside the open_input_file() call.  Maybe the file is still locked ?

Edit:  I just checked the code.  I have modified your english_to_morse() function.  1. The **while** statement is easier to follow than the **for**.  2. fgetc() returns an int and not a char.

At the top of the initialise I added this.  This initialises every string in the array with and undefined string of ".??.".  This will make it easier to find strange bugs as everything in your array is at least initialised.

I have modified different sections of the code but you should be able to follow.

```
    initialize_morse_alphanum (char morseStrings[91][6])
    {   
        for (int i=0;i<91;i++)
            strcpy(morseStrings[i], ".??.");

        ....
        ....



    void 
    english_to_morse(FILE* inputFile, FILE* outputFile, char morseStrings[91][6])
    {   int convert;

        convert = fgetc(inputFile);
        while (convert != EOF)
        {   
            fputs(morseStrings[convert], outputFile);
            fputc(' ', outputFile);
            printf ("%s ", morseStrings[convert]);
            convert = fgetc(inputFile);
        }
    }


open_output_file (char* fileName)  //opens destination file to be written
{   FILE* handle = NULL;
    handle = fopen (fileName, "w");    <---- Remove the * from filename
    return handle; }
```

Also, as mentioned in a different answer, it would be good to add some bounds checks to different areas of the code.  At the moment it is quite prone to crashing.  If my input file contains a lowercase 'a' (ascii 96) your program will be accessing memory that is out of bounds.  So you should add a line like if (convert >= '0' && convert <= 'Z') in there somewhere.  I will let you work that out.

Comment: 1. yes.    2. just implemented that, and it displayed the expected value.     3. no. I call fclose() in main() after open_input_file() (although, it never gets to that point before encountering a run-time error)

Comment: open_output_file (char* fileName)  //opens destination file to be written
{ FILE* handle = NULL;
 handle = fopen (*fileName, "w");
 return handle;
}
You need change the middle line to   handle = fopen(filename, "w");  / ie.  remove the *

Comment: I would also recommend that a good practice to follow is that you write one function at a time, compile and then test it fully before starting to write the next function.  This way you find bugs as you go.  In this case there were small errors in different areas of your program and it made testing and debugging more difficult.  This is something you learn to do well over time but is a good habit to get into now.

Comment: That probably would have saved me quite a bit of time today.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way. I'm going to implement the error-checking you recommended

Comment: There is much more to learn but take it one step at a time though.  Learning by doing is the best way to learn and you seem to have the right attitude to do well.  At this rate you will learn very quickly.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `gather_input` works properly. Could it be a problem because you're trying to read a file you're also writing on? In this case, try to close and open again the stream.

Comment: I don't think gather_input is the problem. What do you mean I'm trying to read a file I'm writing in? When am I writing in that file?